# How to arrange array values on a table for email?

Tags: javascript, arrays, email, html-table

Sorry for the vague title. I'm really new to programming and I have this code here:

```
 function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Confirm Order')
      .addItem('Send Email', 'email')
      .addToUi();  
}  

function email() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var currentRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var product = sheet.getRange(2,5,1,11).getValues(); //header names
  var order1 = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 5, 1,11).getValues();
  var order2 = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 17, 1,11).getValues();
  var order3 = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 29, 1,11).getValues();
  var email = sheet.getRange(currentRow,2).getValues();

  var tab = ""
  var z ="";

  for(var i in product){
    if(product[i]!="") z += "<tr><td style='padding:5px'>" + product[i] + "</td><td style='padding:5px'>" + order1[i] + "</td><td style='padding:5px'>" + order2[i] + "</td><td style='padding:5px'>" + order3[i] + "</td></tr>";
  }

  tab = "<table><tr><th>Product Name</th><th>Order 1</th> <th>Order 2</th> <th>Order 3</th></tr>" + z + "</table>";

//  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),"Your report", report, {htmlBody: report});
  MailApp.sendEmail(email,"Order Confirmation", tab, {htmlBody: tab});
}
```

The following code sends out an email of a selected data in a spreadsheet, however the results in email are not one below another. For example, I want it to look like this:

```
Product Name      order 1     order 2     order 3
prod A               2           2           1
prod B               3           1           4
Prod C               12          7           9
```

But it ends up looking like this:

```
Product Name           order 1     order 2     order 3
prod A,prod B,prod C    2,3,12      2,1,7       1,4,9
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I really wanted to learn.

Comment: `getValues` is returning a 2D array - data[row][col].

Comment: Thanks for replying but what do I need to do to fix it? Sorry if it's such a dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getValues` returns a 2d array. This is why `product[0]` displays as "prod A,prod B,prod C". That's the arrays `toString` function at work. So you need to print `product[0][0]`, `product[0][1]`, `product[0][2]`.

```
for(var i in product) {
    for (var j in product[i]) {
        z += "<tr><td style='padding:5px'>" + product[i][j] + "</td><td style='padding:5px'>" + order1[i][j] + "</td><td style='padding:5px'>" + order2[i][j] + "</td><td style='padding:5px'>" + order3[i][j] + "</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

This assumes `product`, `order1`, `order2`, and `order3` all have the same size.

Comment: Wow thanks Johnny! Works perfect now. I did a few lessons in codecademy because I really wanted to learn the language. I'll keep pushing myself hard in a hope that someday I could be as good as you and would definitely pay it forward. Thanks again!